# If $f(x) \geq g(x)\ \forall x \in [0,1]$, prove that $\int_0^1 f \geq \int_0^1 g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, proof-verification, riemann-integration

Suppose that $f, g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are Riemann integrable and $f(x) \geq g(x)\ \forall x \in [0,1]$. Show that $\int_0^1 f \geq \int_0^1 g$.

So this should be relatively simple. We have $f$ is Riemann integrable
if $L(f) = U(f)$. Where $L(f) = sup\{L(f,P)\ |\ \text{P a partition}\}$, $U(f) = inf\{U(f,P)\ |\ \text{P a partition}\}$.

Now we have that $f(x) \geq g(x)\ \forall x \in [0,1]$. Because this holds, we have $L(f) \geq L(g)$. Since $\int_0^1$ is the common value $L(f) = U(f)$. We have $U(f) \geq U(g)$ as well. And so $\int_0^1 f \geq \int_0^1 g$.

Not too versed in proving stuff of this sort so would appreciate help/clarification.

Comment: I see the pieces of a complete proof... just oddly ordered. You have in the assumptions that $f$ and $g$ are integrable. Don't need to show it.

Comment: I suppose you've glossed over an important piece. If you know $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x$, how do you know that $L(f,P)\geq L(g,P)$ for any $P$ immediately? Lower/upper sums aren't built directly from functions values. (This would be easy with Riemann sums though)

Comment: With doing it with Riemann sums, would it be correct to say that considering the Riemann sum, $I(f, P, \{t_i\}) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) \cdot (x_i - x_i-1)$, we have that this sum is larger for a partition with respect to $f$ than with $g$. So therefore, we have that the integral is greater.

Comment: Pretty much. With Riemann sums, the inequalities are almost immediate just from ordered field properties.

Comment: You are making assertions without proof.  Once you establish $L(f,P) \geqslant L(g,P)$ for any $P$, the next inference should be $\int_0^1f \geqslant L(f,P) \geqslant L(g,P)$. Now that the LHS is free of dependence on $P$ you can say $\int_0^1f \geqslant \sup_P L(g,P)$ and you are finished.

Comment: It *might* be easier if you let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, so $h(x) \ge 0 \, \forall x \in [0,1]$. Now show that $\int_0^1 h(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx-\int_0^1 g(x) dx \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it, but for someone at your stage, I would expect some explanation of why $f(x) \ge g(x)$ implies $L(f) \ge L(g)$, especially since this is the main part of the proof.